# Yield continue?

Tags: c#, loops, ienumerable, yield

***OP edit:*** This was a bad question predicated upon a misunderstanding of how `yield return` works. The short answer: If you don't want to `yield return` something, don't `yield return` anything.

---

There's `yield return` to return the next element in the collection and then there's `yield break` to end the iteration.  Is there a sort of `yield continue` to tell the loop controller to skip to the next element?

Here's what I am trying to achieve, though it obviously doesn't build:

```
static IEnumerable<int> YieldTest()
{
    yield return 1;
    yield return 2;
    yield continue;
    yield return 4;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you add some code to clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What do you expect to happen after `yield continue`? What would the caller receive? Why not just go with `yield return 4;` after `2`?

Comment: @BartoszKP That is *just an example*.  I also tried just using continue within my method, but it doesn't build because it's not valid.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin I know it's an example. I'm asking how do you expect this example to behave. It's unclear what do you need it for. Usually I would just write `yield return 1`, `yield return 2`, `yield return 4`. And the client would receive three integers, 1, 2, 4. What do you want to happen on the client-side between 2 and 4?

Comment: @oscilatingcretin `continue` can be used within a loop **only**.

Comment: I'm hard pressed to imagine a problem a 2k+ user has with this. Do you want `foreach (int i in YieldTest()) Print(i)` to print `1 2 4`? But that's as simple as omitting the third line. _soconfused_

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is no need to have a separate `yield continue` statement. Just use `continue` or any other conditional statement to skip the element as you need within your enumeration algorithm.

The enumeration algorithm that uses `yield` is internally transformed into a state machine by the compiler, which can the be invoked several times. The point of `yield` is that it generates an output, effectively pausing / stopping the state machine at the place where it's used. The effect of a possible `yield continue` would be none at all in respect to the behavior of the state machine. Hence it is not needed.

Example:

```
static IEnumerable<int> YieldTest()
{
    for (int value = 1; value <= 4; value++)
    {
        if (value == 3) continue;  // alternatively use if (value != 3) { … }
        yield return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter Feel free to comment what you thing is wrong with my answer, so that it can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the information about a hole in your data to the caller, then use nullable:

```
static IEnumerable<int?> YieldTest()
{
    yield return 1;
    yield return 2;
    yield return null;
    yield return 4;
}
```